# How to create makefile for lexical analyzer?

Tags: c, makefile, lex, lexical-analysis

I want to make a make file for my lexical analyzer using flex ,I have tried to many templates of make files but it did not work so please help me build one here is the lines to compile the code:

```
lex -t lexical.l > lexical.c
cc -c -o lexical.o lexical.c
cc -o lexy lexical.o -ll
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A starting point would be

```
LEX = lex

.l.c:
        $(LEX) -t $< >$@

.c.o:
        $(CC) -o $@ -c $<

lexy: lexical.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ -ll
```

This needs to be extended with `clean` rules, dependency tracking and so on, but I think you should be able to get the idea how Makefiles work.

Comment: what is the difference comparing to the above answer

Answer (score 7):

If you're using GNU make you don't need a makefile at all. Built-in rules cover your use case.

Let's print built-in rules and see whether make knows how to transform '%.l' to '%.c'.

```
$ make -p | grep -A6 '\.l\.c'
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
.l.c:
#  Implicit rule search has not been done.
#  Modification time never checked.
#  File has not been updated.
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
    @$(RM) $@ 
     $(LEX.l) $< > $@
```

It does. In a similar way you can check that GNU make knows how to build '%.o' from '%.c' and a '%' executable from '%.o'.

Assuming that there's a `lexical.l` in the current directory and there's no makefile let's see how would make build `lexical`.

```
$ make -n lexical
rm -f lexical.c 
lex  -t lexical.l > lexical.c
cc    -c -o lexical.o lexical.c
cc   lexical.o   -o lexical
rm lexical.c lexical.o
```

Great. All we miss is the `-ll` flag for linking you asked for. Let's add it to `LDLIBS`.

```
$ make -n lexical LDLIBS=-ll
rm -f lexical.c 
lex  -t lexical.l > lexical.c
cc    -c -o lexical.o lexical.c
cc   lexical.o  -ll -o lexical
rm lexical.c lexical.o
```

Voilà! As a result your makefile can be as short as

```
LDLIBS=-ll
all: lexical
```

Comment: I did not understand what should be in the final make file?

Comment: Two final lines of my answer.

Comment: I get the following when I run make command :~/hedor1>make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: I guess you're running make in a directory without a makefile.

Comment: I put one named MAKE and inside of it as you have said!

Comment: Rename it to `Makefile`. Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

GNU make has already defined the necessary rules for this. Just put this in a file named `Makefile`

```
LDLIBS = -ll

lexy: lexical.o

lexical.o: lexical.l
```

and run

> $ make

and you're done.